# The correct formula for computing the daily and weekly food expenses

Tags: python, formula

Ive been racking my head with this problem for the past couple of mins and was wondering what is wrong with my code and the right formula for it to work I am trying to get it to work like in the image given.
Here is my code

```
# Write your solution here
times_week = float(input("How many times a week do you eat at the student cafeteria?"))
lunch_price = float(input("The price of a typical student lunch"))
groceries_spent = float(input("How much money do you spend on groceries in a week?"))
daily = float((times_week + lunch_price + groceries_spent) / 7)
weekly = daily * 7

print("Average food expenditure: ")
print(f"{daily}")
print(f"{weekly}")
```

output should be
[image]

but all i got is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be this:

```
times_week = float(input("How many times a week do you eat at the student cafeteria?"))
lunch_price = float(input("The price of a typical student lunch"))
groceries_spent = float(input("How much money do you spend on groceries in a week?"))

daily = float((times_week * lunch_price + groceries_spent) / 7)

weekly = daily * 7

print("Average food expenditure: ")
print(f"{daily}")
print(f"{weekly}")
```

You just need to swap the `+` in between your `times_week` and `lunch_price` for a `*`

But I'd also recommend doing weekly first and then daily. It doesn't make much sense to find the weekly essentially in your daily formula and then divide it by seven and then multiply it by seven. I'd suggest doing this:

```
times_week = float(input("How many times a week do you eat at the student cafeteria?"))
lunch_price = float(input("The price of a typical student lunch"))
groceries_spent = float(input("How much money do you spend on groceries in a week?"))

weekly = float(times_week * lunch_price + groceries_spent)

daily = weekly / 7

print("Average food expenditure: ")
print(f"{daily}")
print(f"{weekly}")
```

Comment: And of course add the formatting at the end when you print with the euros and such, but I thought that went without saying.